# react-csv component not generating file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am new to react-csv component and struggling to download the csv which this component should return back to the user. below is an extract of my code.
I double checked the data returned from my API. Its an array of objects.
Please can you help out?

```
export default function ProductsTableFooter({ ...props }) {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);



    useEffect(() => {
        handleDownloadCSV();
    }, []);

    const handleDownloadCSV = async () => {
        try {
            console.log('clicked')
            const data = await axios.get(
                `http://api.myapiaddress.local/csv/products?fornitore=10&utilizzo=0&stato=Liquido&nome=cor`,
            );
            const resData = Papa.parse(data.data, { header: true, dynamicTyping: true }).data;
            setData(resData);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };


    return (
        <div className="flex flex-row rounded px-2 py-1 mt-2 text-white mr-4 mb-8 " style={{ background: colors.tableHeaderColor }}>

            <div className="flex flex-row justify-start items-center flex-1">

                <div>
                    <RoundButton icon={<FaFileCsv size={23} />} onClick={handleDownloadCSV} />
                    <CSVLink
                        headers={["a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e"]}
                        target="_blank"
                        filename={"prodotti"}
                        data={data}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div >
    );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Danfojs? I don't know react-csv, but Danfojs is quite similar to Pandas: https://danfo.jsdata.org/api-reference/input-output/danfo.to_csv

Answer (score 0):

In react-csv docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv, I see that if setting `target="_blank"`, they use component CSVDownload. Y can try it:
`<CSVDownload data={csvData} target="_blank" />;`